# Microsoft Sync Framework with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, frameworks, synchronization, nosql

we are developing a multiplateforme mobile application thats support synchronization with NoSQL backend, we are looking if Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0 CTP can be used to solve all synchronization problems using a non-microsoft backend,

Sync Framework 4.0 allow several devices on any plateforme to achive synchronization tasks by exposing an oData service, this can be done by using Sync Framework Toolkit, but use SQL Server or SQL Azure as backend on the service side,

the application we are developing should use NoSQL database server (MongoDB) on its server side and I realy dont know if Microsoft Sync Framework could be used with this DBMS and how it should be done,

if someone have achieved this by customizing Microsoft Sync Framework provider please share your experience, links or any helpful things,

thanks in advance,

Comment: I know this is an age old question but I would like to know whether you succeeded in customizing the sync framework. I have similar requirements now (more specifically from SQLite to Neo4j) and am unable to find any good solutions for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mrinal :

I started writting a Microsoft Sync Framework MongoDB Provider but i realized later that i had to implement a good part of Sync Framework, so I have removed all dependencies between Sync Framework and Sync Framework Toolkit to take juste the infrastructure part of Sync Framework Toolkit and i implemented my own synchronization logic inside, i've also updated the client side to use my NoSQL To SQL ORM to store data on Client-SQLite db.

I suggest you to use SyncFoundation if you have no time to do all this tasks, Sync foundation is a lightweight version of Sync Framework but more flexible if you have to use a non microsoft backend, the home page of sync foundation is (https://github.com/mschoneman/SyncFoundation).

Answer (score 0):

there is no out-of-the-box sync provider for MongoDB, so you will have to write your own.

assuming you can write your own, you will have to modify the Sync Toolkit server side component to replace the SqlSyncProvider with your custom MongoDB provider.

I suggest you check out the licensing of the Sync Framework Toolkit as well. if I remember it right, the client components is on Apache license but the server side is on MSPL.

Comment: Thank you JuneT, I'll check the license of Sync Framework Toolkit and look if it's possible to customize the tool.